# Update CMS Blocks Status Programmatically issue

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, cms-block

I have created a cron that in configured date enables or disables some CMS blocks.

It works fine only for disabling action and not for enabling.
It's so strange because I call the same method:

```
Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($block)->setData('is_active', 1)->save();
```

to enable **DOESN'T WORK**

```
Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($block)->setData('is_active', 0)->save();
```

to disable **WORKS**

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know it its work :

```
Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($block)->setData('is_active', 1)->save();
```

OR

```
Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('identifier','my_block_id')->addStoreFilter($store, true)->load()->setData('content', 'Example content')->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the first advice works but I need to load  block for specific store; the second one doesn't work.

Meanwhile I discovered a strange behavior: trying to load a block for a store

`$cms_block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($blocks_to_active[$row]);`

and printing it I obtain two different array.

If the block is _enabled_ the result is an array full of information ([block_id], [title], [is_active] etc.) but if the block is _disabled_ these data are not available.

So, how can I load the info for a disasbled CMS block?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $cmsBlock = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter($store->getId())
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', $identifier)
        ->setPageSize(1)
        ->getFirstItem();
```

You **need** to use a collection to safely load cms blocks in Magento 1 (and 2 IIRC).

This is because `Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Block::_getLoadSelect` does an `is_active=1` check if you try and load it by store scope.

```
protected function _getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object)
{
    $select = parent::_getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object);

    if ($object->getStoreId()) {
        $stores = array(
            (int) $object->getStoreId(),
            Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID,
        );

        $select->join(
            array('cbs' => $this->getTable('cms/block_store')),
            $this->getMainTable().'.block_id = cbs.block_id',
            array('store_id')
        )->where('is_active = ?', 1)
        ->where('cbs.store_id in (?) ', $stores)
        ->order('store_id DESC')
        ->limit(1);
    }

    return $select;
}
```

Using a collection allows you to bypass this hardcoded load select filtering.

Using a collection to load the CMS block does not trigger all the same observers etc that you would expect, so if you are planning on calling `$cmsBlock->save()` at the end of your modifications you will have to be sure to re-attach the store information.

```
$cmsBlock->setData('foo', 'bar');
$existingStoreIds = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getResource()->lookupStoreIds($cmsBlock->getId());
$cmsBlock->setData('stores', $existingStoreIds);
$cmsBlock->save();
```